# Google Chrome Selenium XPATH doesnt work(click the button)

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

username = "x"
password = "y"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
s = Service("C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(http\\...)


uname = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="login")
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(username)


pword = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="password")
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(password)


button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[1]/main/section/div/div[2]/div/form/button")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button)
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
errors = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "flash-error")

if any(error_message in e.text for e in errors):
    print("[!] Login failed")
else:
    print("[+] Login successful")

driver.close()
```

[[image: This is DOM]] (Copy link and paste it in browser if it doesnt`t open)

I tried different ways such as ID, CSS and link text.As you can see here`s my code I think it must working fine.

Comment: can you show us the error message?

Comment: Well, thanks for answering. The thing is that there is no error message. The click function simply doesn't work. At the end of the code i can see that log in was successful. But i am not moving to next page! I tried everything possible with xpath but with no result. I simply do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: [+] Login successful

Process finished with exit code 0